# Bitrix24 API NAV_PARAMS `task.elapseditem.getlist`

Tags: javascript, node.js, битрикс, битрикс24

столкнулся со странной проблемой при работе с [API Bitrix24](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/tasks/task/elapseditem/getlist.php) `task.elapseditem.getlist`:

```
import Bitrix from '@2bad/bitrix';
const bitrix = Bitrix(WEB_HOOK);
const {result: bitrixLimitTimes}: any = await bitrix.call('task.elapseditem.getlist' as any,
                [
                    {'ID': 'desc'},
                    {
                        '>=CREATED_DATE': (new Date()).toDateString(),
                    },
                    {
                        NAV_PARAMS: { // постраничка
                            nPageSize: 2,   // по 2 элемента на странице.
                            iNumPage: 2,    // страница номер 2
                        },
                    },
                ] as any,
            );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запросе лимитированного количества данных через NAV_PARAMS `{nPageSize: 2, iNumPage: 1}`. Получаю 400 ошибку. В документации удалось найти следующий код от другого [метода](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/tasks/task/item/list.php):

```js
BX24.callMethod(
    'task.item.list',
    [
        {ID : 'desc'},      // Сортировка по ID — по убыванию.
        {ID: [1,2,3,4,5,6]},    // Фильтр
        {   
            NAV_PARAMS: { // постраничка
                nPageSize : 2,  // по 2 элемента на странице.
                iNumPage  : 2   // страница номер 2        
            }
        }
    ],
    function(result)
    {
        console.info(result.data());
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

Без пагинации всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, что при отправлении запроса в bitrix24 важна не просто последовательность, а также и полное наличие всех параметров, что странно при условии, что поддерживается передача параметров в виде JSON и при этом тот же параметр `filter`  не являются обязательным, как и параметр `select`, но при этом при использовании `params` их нужно обязательно указать, особенно это странно на фоне того, что параметр `TASKID`, тоже является необязательным и без него всё работает отлично.

```js
const {result: bitrixLimitTimes}: any = await bitrix.call('task.elapseditem.getlist' as any,
                {
                    order: {
                        'ID': 'desc',
                    },
                    filter: (isSyncCurrentDay) ? {
                        '>=CREATED_DATE': (new Date()).toDateString(),
                    } : {'>ID': 1},
                    select: ['ID', 'TASK_ID', 'SECONDS', 'CREATED_DATE'],
                    params: {
                        NAV_PARAMS: { // постраничка
                            nPageSize: 2,   // по 2 элемента на странице.
                            iNumPage: 2,    // страница номер 2
                        },
                    },
                },
            );
```

Надеюсь, что ребята из Bitrix поправят свой "великолепный" API и выделят денег на архитектора.